# Singleton does not keep changed properties

Tags: c#, android, design-patterns, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a bluetoothscanner class as a Singleton, this way throughout my whole application i'm able to communicate with the bluetoothscanner.

I thought when setting a property of a Singleton it would remain his value, apparently it does not? or am i doing something wrong?

This is my singleton:

```
public sealed class BluetoothScanner
{
    private static readonly BluetoothScanner instance = new BluetoothScanner();
    public static BluetoothScanner Instance => BluetoothScanner.instance;

    public bool IsConnected { get; set; }

    private BluetoothScanner()
    {
        this.Adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
    }

    public bool Connect()
    {
        var bondedDevices = this.Adapter.BondedDevices;
        if (!bondedDevices.Any())
        {
            this.SendToastMessage("No paired devices found");
            this.IsConnected = false;
        }
        if (this.socket.ConnectAsync().IsCompleted)
        {
            this.SendToastMessage($"Connected to Device {this.device.Name}");
            this.IsConnected = true;
        }
        return this.IsConnected;
    }
}
```

The `Connect` method is called like this in my fragment:

```
public class ConditionSearchFragment : BaseTitledFragment<ConditionSearchViewModel>
{
    protected override int FragmentId => Resource.Layout.fragment_condition_search;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (!BluetoothScanner.Instance.IsConnected)
        {
            BluetoothScanner.Instance.Connect();
        }
        BluetoothScanner.Instance.SendKey += this.OnSendKey;
        BluetoothScanner.Instance.SendToast += this.OnSendToast;
        return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

I thought on the first time it'll initialize the singleton and then reuse it over and over again. Aparently when returning back to this class and `OnCreateView()` is called again it says it's not connected thus trying to connect using the connect method, thus getting an Java.IO.Exception as there's already an open socket..

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add <application android:name="yoursingleton" to your manifest?

Comment: @ScottS no i didn't even know i had to do so? What would i add to it when my class lives in at this namespace: `Some.Fancy.Namespace.Droid.Bluetooth.BluetoothScanner`

Comment: Your singleton implementation look correct. Maybe there's some android specific in there. Maybe instances get collected when you change activities via an intent (because it's handled on OS level and may cause the Mono Runtime to close).

Comment: Why you are using readonly in this line? Can you remove it and try?
private static readonly BluetoothScanner instance = new BluetoothScanner();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your singleton works as expected.  The only thing I can come up with is that your call to connect() is failing in some manner thus not setting the IsConnected to true.
test this line for the return value:

```
BluetoothScanner.Instance.Connect();
```

I suspect that this line:

```
if (this.socket.ConnectAsync().IsCompleted)
```

returns a false thus leaving IsConnected to default to false.

Comment: Hmmm would be weird if it fails.. since my bluetooth devices are able to connect after base.oncreateview is called. altough since it's an async method and is not awaited this might indeed be it.. Gonna test tomorrow ;)

Comment: As it was running async the main thread didn't keep track of it and while it was not awaited it never was completed at time of checking thus not setting IsConnected. How would one make it wait for it to end? Right now i'm using the `this.socket.Connect()` method which is blocking...